# Auto scaling ffmpeg in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, supervisord, autoscaling

I am a newbie to aws platform. I would like to know how I could enable auto scaling for my application below

https://github.com/riyaskp/PHP-Video-Transcoder

The application is used to transcode the user uploaded video to mp4.
It is using PHP and rabbitmq for managing the upload and queue and FFMPEG for transcoding. The rabbitmq workers are configured using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

The supervisor runs 8 consumer process to enable parallel execution of ffmpeg on 8 core CPU in a single AWS instant.

I would like to know how I can scale or how I need to approach this application to enable more parallel ffmpeg process when all the 8 process are transcoding.  what will be the right aproach in aws?

Thankyou for the help.

Comment: a general idea will be very helpful

Comment: Have you tried AWS Transcoder ?

Comment: AWS Transcoder is too expensive. I am looking for an alternative to build. Its working perfectly in a single instant. would like to know the steps to make it autoscale. The project have a docker file. and we have to run the supervisord after docker installed. I don't have idea how to auto start the supervisord after the docker install